# How does EventHandler<ActionEvent> get automatically called when button is pressed?

Tags: java, javafx

To test my understanding of interfaces in Java, I have pulled the anonymous class in a button click event handler into a separate class - which has worked - but there is something I do not understand about why it has worked.

I was expecting to have to call the `handle()` method of my class myself but it seems that passing my EventHandler implementation as a parameter is all that I need to do. Clicking the button is obviously calling the `handle()` method, I'm just not clear on why that is.

**Anonymous Class version**

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
      }
  });
```

**Separate Class version**

```
public class HelloWorldEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }                
}
```

```
btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'"); 
HelloWorldEventHandler handler = new HelloWorldEventHandler();
btn.setOnAction(handler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [part of the JavaFX `Button` definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty--). Check out `setOnAction()` and `onActionProperty()`.

The `onActionProperty()` method returns a wrapped version of the `EventHandler` which you provide. It describes its returned object as:

> The button's action, which is invoked whenever the button is fired. This may be due to the user clicking on the button with the mouse, or by a touch event, or by a key press, or if the developer programmatically invokes the fire() method.

I.e., when you `setOnAction()`, the thing you're setting *is invoked whenever the button is fired*.